# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I've been watching a calculator project and everything seemed to be fine (the code was alright, it's same as it shown in the video) but I got this error, I don't know what is happening.

```
class Calculator {
     constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
         this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
         this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
         this.clear();
     };

     clear() {
         this.previousOperand = '';
         this.currentOperand = '';
         this.operation = undefined;
     };

     delete() {

     };

     appendNumber(number) {
         if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
         this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
     };

     chooseOperation(operation) {
         this.operation = operation;
         this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
         this.currentOperand = '';

     };

     compute() {

     };

     updateDisplay() {
         this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
         this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand;
     };
 };

 const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
 const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
 const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
 const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
 const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
 const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
 const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

 const calculator = new Calculator;

 numberButtons.forEach(button => {
     button.addEventListener('click', () => {
         calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
         calculator.updateDisplay();
     });
 });

 operationButtons.forEach(button => {
     button.addEventListener('click', () => {
         calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
         calculator.updateDisplay();
     });
 });
```

I gonna post a photo so you can see more in depth

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see any errors on console?!

Comment: The error probably refers to `this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText` and simply means that when the error occurs, `this.currentOperandTextElement` is `undefined`. Those are set in the constructor, but you don't pass the two elements when creating the calculator instance here: `const calculator = new Calculator;` Double check that line in your tutorial, it should be `const calculator = new Calculator(..., ...);`

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass any parameters to your `Calculator` constructor when called here

```js
const calculator = new Calculator;
```

Look how it is defined

```js
constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
```

So it should be called like this

```js
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right haha. Now it's working, thank you for your help :D.